# async errors with function call inside nested async loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, async.js

I am working on a pothole map, and am on the stage where I load pothole data from the server and put it on the map as markers. Since data retrieval and the APIs that my app relies on (Roads, Geolocation, etc.) are asynchronous, my code ended up refactored to run asynchronously. I refactored the code blocks that added the markers to the map to this:

```
/* put all potholes on the map 
 * Parameters:
 *  • callback : the function to call next
 */
function addPotholeMarkers(callback)
{
    var DEBUG = false;
    // guarantee that callback is function
    if ((callback) && (typeof(callback) !== 'function')) throw new TypeError('callback is something, but not a function. Thrown from addPotholeMarkers().');
    // add all the markers for them to the map
    async.waterfall([
        function(cb) { 
            async.eachOf(potholeAddresses, function(value, key) {
                async.eachOf(value, function (v, k) { 
                    addPotholeMarker(v, false);
                })
            })
            if (cb && typeof cb === 'function') cb(null);
        }, function(cb) {
            async.eachOf(potholeCoordinates, function(value, key) { 
                async.eachOf(value, function(v, k) { 
                    async.setImmediate(function() { addPotholeMarker(v); }); // This came from 
                })
            })
        }], function(err, results) {
            console.log('trying to center map');
            reCenterMap();
            console.log('Map recentered');
            if (callback) { 
                callback(err);
            }
        });


}
```

and `addPotholeMarker()` looks something like:

```
/* code was initially obtained from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/inspector */
/* Adds marker to map.
 * Parameters : 
 *  • potholeData  : a PotholeData (or PotholeDataFromCoords) object
 *  • snappedToRoad: boolean
 * Returns : 
 *  • the marker that was added to the map, or null if arguments invalid
 */
function addPotholeMarker(potholeData, snappedToRoad) {
  // make sure potholeState is either falsy or contains iconURL string
  if ((!potholeData.potholeState) || ((potholeData.potholeState) && (potholeData.potholeState.iconURL === undefined))) throw new Error('invalid potholeData');
  // let's make sure to snap this to road if it isn't already...  
  var coords = new GPSCoordinates(potholeData.lat, potholeData.lng);
  if (!snappedToRoad) 
  { 
    var potholeMarker = 'a garbage return value';
    getRoadCoordinates(coords).done(function(response) {
        var coords = response.snappedPoints[0].location;
        potholeData.lat = coords.latitude;
        potholeData.lng = coords.longitude;
        return (potholeMarker = addPotholeMarker(potholeData, true));
   /*     potholeMarker = addPotholeMarker(potholeData, true);
        return potholeMarker;*/
    });
    return; 
    //return potholeMarker;
  }
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: coords,
    title: coords.toString(),
    map: map,
    opacity: 0.5,
    icon: ((potholeData.potholeState.iconURL !== undefined) ? potholeData.potholeState.iconURL : PURPLE_MARKER)
  });

  // make marker have effect when mouseout,mouseover
  marker.addListener('mouseover', function(mouseEvent) {
    marker.setOpacity(1.0);
  });
  marker.addListener('mouseout', function(mouseEvent) {
    marker.setOpacity(0.5);

  });

  var infoWindow = createInfoWindow(potholeData);
  // save infoWindow for later reference
  infoWindows[statesMap.get(getPotholeStateFor(potholeData.potholeState))].push(infoWindow);
  // on click of marker, show infoWindow
  marker.addListener('click', function(mouseEvent) { 
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  // add this to potholeMarkers
  potholeMarkers[statesMap.get(getPotholeStateFor(potholeData.potholeState))].push(marker);  
  return marker;
}
```

[This app is hosted on Google Apps Script](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyzys_DLN1wNv9u0tX_i5ayETAIjyX8FTPRiFy7yJ59EP0og58/exec) (you'll need Google account to run this), and uses the client-side [async library](https://caolan.github.io/async/index.html)

This code, when ran successfully, is supposed to re-center the map at the position-average of all the markers. `reCenterMap()` works as it should, so I omitted it in attempt at MVCE.

**When I ran the code**

During any tick of the asynchronous loop, the members of the `potholeCoordinates` object (which is an `Object<Array<PotholeData> >`) appear empty. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After showing a friend this problem, contemplating his advice on this, and staying up last night for a few hours to work on it myself, I made the following changes:

1. *not related to this problem, but*

I changed the index `statesMap.get(getPotholeStateFor(potholeData.potholeState))` to `statesMap.get(getPotholeStateFor(potholeData))`. Turns out that I gave `getPotholeStateFor()` the wrong object, which made it return the wrong state.

1. I changed the signature of `addPotholeMarker(potholeData, snappedToRoad)` to `addPotholeMarker(potholeData, snappedToRoad, callback)`; /* because apparently I forgot that, with async functions, callbacks must be passed to the lowest level functions and invoked there, with signature `callback(err, results)` or something similar */
2. Inside `addPotholeMarker()` I made sure to use `callback`, but in a modular way:

   `if (callback) return callback(null, potholeMarker);
   return potholeMarker;`
   /* I applied this change to the `if (!snappedToRoad)`, but that if-statement is still broken: it will return before it finishes its task of appending to array, and `return callback(null, potholeMarker)` will cause the callback to be invoked twice. I may end up having to refactor this whole function, especially to append to `potholeMarkers` (which, btw, is global) **after** this function (it will be the callback to this) */
3. The innermost async loop in `addPotholeMarkers()` got changed from :

   `async.eachOf(value, function(v, k) { 
                   async.setImmediate(function() { addPotholeMarker(v); });
               })`

to

`async.eachSeries(value, function(pothole, fn) { 
                    addPotholeMarker(pothole, 
                        true,
                        //pothole.isSnappedToRoad(),
                        fn); 
                })`

**NOTE** `pothole.isSnappedToRoad()` is commented out because it returns false, and `addPotholeMarker()` doesn't work right in the main call stack with the second parameter false. Also, it should return true, but it isn't because this type of error happened in function prior to `addPotholeMarkers()`; /* I'm going to fix that next! */